# I don't believe this question should have been closed or deleted

Tags: discussion, specific-question

https://stackoverflow.com/q/15908116

OP was trying to pass the value of `processId` and was passing the string `"processId"` instead.

The question was clear, the answer was clear. The only possible hitch I can see is that the code that showed the `processId`/`"processId"` confusion was visible only after a right-scroll.

I cannot vote to undelete because Community (and its moderator-like powers) deleted the post.

Comment: Once again... Community is a bot, not a moderator.

Comment: And typos do not make great questions anyways.

Comment: It does initially seem like a 'typo' question, but I think you could also look at it as a misunderstanding. I'm going to undelete it. The community (small 'c') can delete it again if they really want.

Comment: @devnull That's a valid point, although it's not obvious to me it was a typo as opposed to just being silly: this kind of thing happens across languages, too.

Comment: @DaveNewton Typo or silly, it doesn't matter.  Chances are that the question doesn't add much value to the site.  Another person making the typo or plain silly wouldn't be able to search such questions either.

Comment: @DaveNewton Ask yourself, who will benefit from this question sticking around?  Who will have their problem solved as a result of this question existing?  I can't imagine anyone.

Comment: @AndrewBarber You seem to have _misused_ your powers.  If you see the question, then you'd figure that the OP has passed two key-value pairs, one correctly and the other incorrectly.  I'd call it a typo.

Comment: Never mind, it's been deleted again `:)`

Comment: Now in the business of specifically targeting and eliminating answers useful *only* to the OP? Everything must be worded and findable in a completely general way? That's a fool's errand: besides being impossible, it eliminates the ability of the site to support a single user. Bye everyone!

Comment: @devnull As I noted - and has happened - the community could overrule me. I think deletion should take any doubt into consideration, and I personally really thought the user thought that was the correct way to do it. But your opinion here counts, too :)

Comment: @DaveNewton The entire *purpose* of this site is to create a useful repository of knowledge for the sake of the entire programming community.  This is a significant divergance for so many of this site's competitors, in that the goal of the question is not primarily to help just the person that asked it, but rather to create a record, accessible through search engines, such that other people with the same problem in the future can find a solution to that same problem.  Helping the person that asked is a secondary goal, not a primary goal.

Comment: Please delete: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827130/how-do-i-call-my-methods-to-my-main-method. Bottom line is that you cannot meet your own expectations, and never will, because they're wrong.

Comment: Please delete: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827415/unknown-crashing. It's just laughable, really. I never subscribed to the "elitist" theory of SO-I think they just spelled "misguided" wrong. You guys are wrong. Not because of intent, but because of execution. You can't, and won't, execute what you say you want.

Comment: There is little point in getting _emotional_.

Answer (score 4):

The question [(in its current state)](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15908116/4) should be closed and deleted. Here's why:

- The title isn't searchable: "Unable to get this syntax correct".  If anyone searches Google for "unable to get this syntax correct" and falls upon this question, I think the odds are slim it will actually solve their problem. That's problem #1
- The question itself doesn't give us clear inputs, outputs, and what they expect to happen.  They tell us one part of the debugging issue, but not in a clear way.
- The answers also don't clearly lay out what the problem is.  I've had to re-read the other answer a few times to realize what the specific issue the OP had, and how it was fixed by that answer.

To have the question undeleted and re-opened, the following needs to happen:

- Improved title. Something I can search for ("Using Url.Action links with JavaScript variables in ASP.NET MVC" or something)
- Clear expectations of the inputs, the outputs, and what is happening vs. what should be happening.
- The answer should be cleaned up, those links aren't really useful because they don't carry a synopsis of the issue found in those links.
- You should expand upon your answer, and go deeper than you went.  Show how to solve the problem (how would I create a URL that used both serverside and JavaScript values?

Overall, this question doesn't add anything to the site, and neither do its answers. It can be salvaged, but it's up to you (the community) to determine if you want to take the time to salvage it.